# CycleDetectedException in maven

Tags: java, maven, scope, dependencies, dependency-properties

Is there a way to avoid CycleDetectedException when compiling my modules?
I explain I have 6 modules:

```
F ==> A ==> B ==> C
              ==> D
              ==> E
```

I want F ==> C and having the same dependency tree
I used the scope provided or runtime but it did not fixed.

Help please

Comment: You have to decouple you code from each other. For example by defining an interface and an appropriate implementation. That sounds like a bad design.

Comment: Please, show us your pom, and explain your notation. Also, read [ask]